# Tkinter photoimage will not display

Tags: python, image, tkinter, urllib

I am trying to use the image from [this webpage](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=414495&type=card) and display it in a Tkinter label. However, whenever I try it the label is created, but the image is blank. It works when I use a url that ends in .jpg (http://i.imgur.com/CC8zIPr.jpg for example). Is there a way to make the first link work correctly? This is the relevant part of my code:

```
url = "http://gatherer.wizards.com/Handlers/Image.ashx?multiverseid=414495&type=card"
u = urlopen(url)
raw_data = u.read()
im = Image.open(io.BytesIO(raw_data))
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
label = tk.Label(image=image)
label.image = image
label.pack()
```

Comment: What type of file are you using? ImageTk can only open .jpg and .gif files. If you want to use a different type of file use the [Python Imaging Library(PIL)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/)

Comment: When I right-click and hit save-as on the image it defaults to jpeg, so I assumed that urlopen is also pulling them down as a jpeg. I may be wrong though.

Comment: It should, but just incase you should try using the PIL module.

Comment: The first four bytes of the data you're reading indicate it is a png file.

Comment: In that case, how do I convert the png to jpg? I can't find any way to do it with PIL without saving the file to the disk.